# Typo3 TSPage-Config: Accessing the flexform-xml fails

Tags: xml, typo3, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths, flexform

i use the bootstrap_package in one project, but the problem is related to accessing felements within the xml in the flexform-databse-column of tt_content (Typo3 v11).
Assuming i have a card_group element with items in it, i tried:

```
TCEFORM {
    tt_content {
        pi_flexform.bootstrap_package {
            sDEF.lDEF.align.disable = 1
            lDEF.align.disable = 1
            sDEF.align.disable = 1
            align.disable = 1
            sDEF.lDEF.columns.removeItems = 4,2,1
            lDEF.columns.removeItems = 4,2,1
            sDEF.columns.removeItems = 4,2,1
            columns.removeItems = 4,2,1
        }
        pi_flexform.tx_bootstrappackage {
            sDEF.lDEF.align.disable = 1
            lDEF.align.disable = 1
            sDEF.align.disable = 1
            align.disable = 1
            sDEF.lDEF.columns.removeItems = 4,2,1
            lDEF.columns.removeItems = 4,2,1
            sDEF.columns.removeItems = 4,2,1
            columns.removeItems = 4,2,1
        }
    }
}
```

My result should have been:

- Field card_groups -> options -> align should be hidden for editors
- Restrict card_groups -> options -> columns to "3" only (as an example)

Any hint / working example on card_groups and/or accessing pi_flexform-fields properly by tsConfig would be highly appreciated.

The XML of the pi_flexform-column of an existing element looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3FlexForms>
    <data>
        <sheet index="sDEF">
            <language index="lDEF">
                <field index="align">
                    <value index="vDEF">center</value>
                </field>
                <field index="columns">
                    <value index="vDEF">3</value>
                </field>
            </language>
        </sheet>
    </data>
</T3FlexForms>
```

Any hint and/or help is highly appreciated.

Thank you, Th.

Comment: The Flexform for Cardgroups seems to be registered for another key: https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/203_content_element_card_group.php#L101. So it's not ` TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.bootstrap_package` but something ending with `...card_group`. The simplest way to find out: have a look into tt_content.pi_flexform of a cardgroup-CE